# Is there only one index use on per table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

thanks for your help.
i had run some test here.
firstly,i run the explain sql statement:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT provinceID FROM city_copy WHERE provinceID>10001 AND cityID=13
```

And the result is:

```
id  select_type  table      type    possible_keys  key     key_len  ref       rows  Extra

------  -----------  ---------  ------  -------------  ------  -------  ------  ------  -------------
 1  SIMPLE       city_copy  ref     proId,cityID   cityID  3        const        1  Using where
```

now the problem is that i had created two index both on provinceID and cityID,but the result showed that there just used cityID instead of used both.

Comment: i feel very sorry for the result is a little mess, now i optimize here

Comment: `id  select_type  table      type    possible_keys  key     key_len  ref       rows  Extra        
------  -----------  ---------  ------  -------------  ------  -------  ------  ------  -------------
     1  SIMPLE       city_copy  ref     proId,cityID   cityID  3        const        1  Using where`

Comment: it chooses which index is best to use. It doesn't hop back and forth

Comment: @Drew,thank you for your tolerance on my unskilled English. according your comment, which means mysql only use a best index as the condition to filter rows?

Comment: no problem. can you please do this, run `show create table city_copy` and publish it at the bottom of you Question (not down here in comments) by clicking on [edit]